# Facebook, Uncaught Error: Tried to get element with id of "%s" but it is not present on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am getting the below error when trying to execute a simple JQuery on browser console for Facebook.

```
Uncaught Error: Tried to get element with id of "%s" but it is not present on the page
```

[image]

Is this any new restriction which has been introduced by Facebook. the same query using the document.getElementById works fine. How is that Facebook is preventing this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this $ symbol is jQuery? Why don't you try document.querySelector for the same, to be sure?

Comment: I have tried both document.querySelector and document.getElementById, in both cases its returns the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched on net whether FB uses JQuery or not and came to know they don't. So `$` here is not jQuery's dollar function.

Typing `$` in console gives this:

```
"function a(a){return g(a,typeof a==="string"?document.getElementById(a):a)}"
```

Based on this I think you should just pass the id. Don't prefix it with `#`. 
You can try this :

```
$('group_mall_785863974804742');
```

Comment: Wow, that works. does this mean that they don't use JQuery at all on their platform or is it  that they use a FB Custom JQuery

Comment: What if you are trying to target with `class`?